# Disable script executed on specific Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want a script (already working) now running on my entire WP website, except on one specific page, the page to which referral goes.

Script that works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDay();

    if (day == 0) {
        window.location="https://example.com/mypage";
    }

</script>
```

I try to put the following code into my functions.php:

```
function my_custom_script() {

    if ( is_page( 'mypage' ) ) {  } 

    else {

        var d = new Date();
        var day = d.getDay();

        if (day == 0) {
            window.location="https://example.com/mypage";
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_script' );
```

The reason I don't want the script to run on the redirect page is because the page will than run into an endless loop.

Can anyone tell me what to do to get it working?

Comment: You simply cant put javascript into a php function. Just do a proper PHP redirect in there rather then javascript

Comment: You can't just mix JS code and PHP code as if they were the same language. Get the day in PHP, then use `header()` to redirect. Much cleaner than doing it with JS anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something; all you want to do is prevent your "Sunday" mypage redirecting to itself when it is a Sunday.

You are already checking at the client side (javascript), so rather than adding more PHP code for WP to process (on every page) it would be simpler to modify your javascript to only redirect if it is not your "Sunday" page.  i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var d = new Date();
  var day = d.getDay();

  if (day == 0) {
    var landingPage = "https://example.com/mypage";
    var currenturl = window.location;
    if(landingPage != currenturl) {
      window.location=landingPage;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That's right, it works! Thanks scytale, and everybody for answering.

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in my comment, you cant put javascript code inside a PHP function and should rather use a PHP redirect using the header function like a so:

```
function my_custom_script() {
    $day = date('d');
    if (0 === $day) {
        header('Location: http://example.org/');
        exit();
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_script');
```

**Note:** Since I never really worked with WordPress (thank god), I havent tested the code. I just adapted your logic :)

Answer (score 0):

**If Javascript is Added in External File.**

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
function my_deregister_javascript()
{
  if ( is_page('YOUR PAGE NAME') )
  {
    wp_deregister_script( 'WORDPRESS JS file NAME' );
  }
}
```

**If Javascript is Hard Coded in Header and Footer**

```
 if ( !is_page('YOUR PAGE NAME') ) 
  {
    <-- Javascript Code Here -->
  }
```